# How to detect which element is firing a scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this demo, and want to apply

```
$('[type=range]').val(scrollPercent);
```

only when `scroll` is calling on wheel scroll and not when the range input is changing. As you can see from the Demo when you try to scroll by changing the range input `$('[type=range]').val(scrollPercent)` also is invoking and causing jumps on Range (please try changing the range and will notice this).

How can I stop this?

```js
$('.post').on('scroll', function(event) {
  var currY = $(this).scrollTop();
  var postHeight = $(this).height();
  var scrollHeight = $('.content').height();
  var scrollPercent = (currY / (scrollHeight - postHeight)) * 100;
  $('[type=range]').val(scrollPercent);
});
$("[type=range]").on('input', function() {
  var val = parseInt($(this).val());
  $('.post').animate({
    scrollTop: (val * 30) + "%"
  }, 5);

});
```

```css
.post {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  top: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container py-2">
  <input type="range" orient="vertical" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider" />
</div>
<div class="container py-2">
  <div class="post" id="mana">
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Technically they are the same, the scroll event fires when the scrollbox has changed its position, no matter if it came from a wheel event, a keyboard press or even programmatically. Your best bet would be to raise a flag in the input handler that you'd lower in the callback of `animate`.

Comment: That is exactly my question Kaiido, how can I set up that Flag?!